# service restart commands from crontab

Tags: cron

I'm running a script that starts a service if not running.
On 'some' RHEL 6.9 servers, the service commands aren't working, If I do the following for debuging:

```
*/1 * * * * sudo /etc/init.d/telegraf status >> /tmp/svc1.log
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * sudo service telegraf status >> /tmp/svc.log
```

Any clue why this happens?

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: Does your `sudo` work without a password? Why not put that in root's `crontab`, or in `/etc/crontab` so you don't need to play with `sudo`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller can't get the service stopped/started/status via cronjob. And apparently, `/tmp/svc.log` is empty.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, the user has sudo access. Service commands works via `sudo su`.
The cron job is listed under `crontab -u root -l`.

Comment: Usually, `sudo` is configured to ask for the user's password, even if a user has access to any and all commands through it. It's somewhat hard to ask for a password interactively from a cron job, which is why I asked about it working _without_ one. But if you're already running that from root's `crontab`, do you need sudo at all?

Comment: and well, usually, when debugging, it's any error messages or log entries that are interesting, not just the fact that it "doesn't work". `cron` should send the (error) output of cronjobs as emails, and your logs should show if the cron job runs at all (somewhere under `/var/log`, I don't know what it is for RHEL)

Comment: Even when the user has `nopasswd` in the sudoers file, they might still need `!requiretty` so you can elevate privileges from your cronjob.

Comment: Try to log along with error, we might get some clue...`sudo /etc/init.d/telegraf status >> /tmp/svc1.log 2>&1`

Comment: @ilkkachu Agree. I removed `sudo` and `/etc/init.d/telegraf status` worked!

Comment: @Jacky cheers!!!